# Doctrine 2.7.4: Get entities with a specific type

Tags: doctrine-orm

I use an Entity `X` like this:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="x")
 */
class X {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Y")
     * @JoinColumn(name="y", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $myY;
}
```

The referenced class `Y` is an abstract base-class for multiple sub-classes. The `$myY` changes from time to time between instances of the sub-classes of `Y`.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"UPLOAD" = "Y1", "PROCESSED" = "Y2", "ERROR" = "Y3"})
 * @Table(name="y")
 */
abstract class Y {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="smallint")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $date;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Y1 extends Y {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->date = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

Now I try to get all instances of `X` from the database which have an instance of `Y1` as `$myY`:

```
$sql = array();
$sql[] = 'SELECT x';
$sql[] = 'FROM my\namespace\X x';
$sql[] = 'WHERE x.myY INSTANCE OF my\namespace\Y1';

$query = $this->em->createQuery(implode(' ', $sql));
$query->setFirstResult($offset);
$query->setMaxResults($maxResults);
return new Paginator($query);
```

But I get a QueryException, it seems not possible to use `x.myY` with `INSTANCE OF`. How I can solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Some tests later:

```
$sql = array();
$sql[] = 'SELECT x';
$sql[] = 'FROM my\namespace\X x JOIN x.myY y';
$sql[] = 'WHERE y INSTANCE OF my\namespace\Y1';

$query = $this->em->createQuery(implode(' ', $sql));
$query->setFirstResult($offset);
$query->setMaxResults($maxResults);
return new Paginator($query);
```

Seems to work.